# How to get the same percent_rank in SQL and pandas?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyspark, hiveql

I was learning `pyspark` which uses `HiveQL` and found it interesting that the percent rank gives two different answers for `pyspark-sql` and `pandas`.

Question Source with sql code: https://www.windowfunctions.com/questions/ranking/3

How to get the same result as SQL in pandas?

## Two Questions

- What is the python code that gives same result as SQL?
- What is the SQL code that gives the same result as pandas?

## pyspark-sql

```py
q = """
select name, weight,
       percent_rank() over (order by weight) as percent_rank_wt
from cats
order by weight
"""
spark.sql(q).show()

SQL gives this table. I would like same table using pandas.

+-------+------+-------------------+
|   name|weight|    percent_rank_wt|
+-------+------+-------------------+
| Tigger|   3.8|                0.0|
|  Molly|   4.2|0.09090909090909091|
|  Ashes|   4.5|0.18181818181818182|
|Charlie|   4.8| 0.2727272727272727|
| Smudge|   4.9|0.36363636363636365|
|  Felix|   5.0|0.45454545454545453|
|   Puss|   5.1| 0.5454545454545454|
| Millie|   5.4| 0.6363636363636364|
|  Alfie|   5.5| 0.7272727272727273|
|  Misty|   5.7| 0.8181818181818182|
|  Oscar|   6.1| 0.9090909090909091|
| Smokey|   6.1| 0.9090909090909091|
+-------+------+-------------------+
```

## pandas

```py
methods = {'average', 'min', 'max', 'first', 'dense'}

df[['name','weight']].sort_values('weight').assign(
     pct_avg=df['weight'].rank(pct=True,method='average'),
     pct_min=df['weight'].rank(pct=True,method='min'),
     pct_max=df['weight'].rank(pct=True,method='max'),
     pct_first=df['weight'].rank(pct=True,method='first'),
     pct_dense=df['weight'].rank(pct=True,method='dense')
).sort_values('weight')
       name  weight   pct_avg   pct_min   pct_max  pct_first  pct_dense
4    Tigger     3.8  0.083333  0.083333  0.083333   0.083333   0.090909
0     Molly     4.2  0.166667  0.166667  0.166667   0.166667   0.181818
1     Ashes     4.5  0.250000  0.250000  0.250000   0.250000   0.272727
11  Charlie     4.8  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333   0.333333   0.363636
3    Smudge     4.9  0.416667  0.416667  0.416667   0.416667   0.454545
2     Felix     5.0  0.500000  0.500000  0.500000   0.500000   0.545455
9      Puss     5.1  0.583333  0.583333  0.583333   0.583333   0.636364
7    Millie     5.4  0.666667  0.666667  0.666667   0.666667   0.727273
5     Alfie     5.5  0.750000  0.750000  0.750000   0.750000   0.818182
8     Misty     5.7  0.833333  0.833333  0.833333   0.833333   0.909091
6     Oscar     6.1  0.958333  0.916667  1.000000   0.916667   1.000000
10   Smokey     6.1  0.958333  0.916667  1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
```

## setup

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContext
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName('app').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': [
        'Molly', 'Ashes', 'Felix', 'Smudge', 'Tigger', 'Alfie', 'Oscar',
        'Millie', 'Misty', 'Puss', 'Smokey', 'Charlie'
    ],
    'breed': [
        'Persian', 'Persian', 'Persian', 'British Shorthair',
        'British Shorthair', 'Siamese', 'Siamese', 'Maine Coon', 'Maine Coon',
        'Maine Coon', 'Maine Coon', 'British Shorthair'
    ],
    'weight': [4.2, 4.5, 5.0, 4.9, 3.8, 5.5, 6.1, 5.4, 5.7, 5.1, 6.1, 4.8],
    'color': [
        'Black', 'Black', 'Tortoiseshell', 'Black', 'Tortoiseshell', 'Brown',
        'Black', 'Tortoiseshell', 'Brown', 'Tortoiseshell', 'Brown', 'Black'
    ],
    'age': [1, 5, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4]
})

schema = StructType([
    StructField('name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('breed', StringType(), True),
    StructField('weight', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('color', StringType(), True),
    StructField('age', IntegerType(), True),
])

sdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df, schema)
sdf.createOrReplaceTempView("cats")
```

Comment: In the question I have given the output of SQL code. My python code gives different result. This means my python code is wrong. I would like to have a "correct" python code that gives the same result as given by SQL code (`percent_rank`).

Comment: can you add a method dense `.rank(pct=True,method='dense')` ?

Comment: Still gives different aswer.

Comment: looks like `pct_dense` is 1 `shift` away from almost there :)

Answer (score 7):

SQL's `percent_rank` is not exactly the same as pandas' `rank`. There are mainly a couple of differences:

- SQL's `percent_rank` **excludes** the current row from the calculations. So if the table has 11 rows, for each row it will calculate the result using only the other 10 rows. pandas `rank` includes all the rows.
- SQL's `percent_rank` gives how many rows are **strictly** smaller than the current one. pandas `rank` doesn't support a method to do that.

## What is the python code that gives same result as SQL?

To get the equivalent of SQL's `percent_rank` in pandas, you can actually perform a small calculation on the `rank` results:

```
(df['weight'].rank(method='min')-1) / (len(df['weight'])-1)
```

the `-1` in the numerator is to get the number of rows strictly smaller than the current row, and the `-1` in the denominator is to get compute the results excluding the current row.

## What is the SQL code that gives the same result as pandas?

it depends on what method you are using in pandas `rank`, but you probably need [SQL's `cume_dist`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cume-dist-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: A simple upvote is not enough, this answer deserves a personal "thank you".